# How can I count a number inside a foreach?

Tags: php

How can I count from 2 up (until the foreach reached the end of the loop)?
Code used:

```
for($i=0;$i<7;$i++) { //loop 7 times
    $date->add(new DateInterval('P1W')); //add one week

    $formatted_time = strftime("%A, %d. %B %Y, %H:%M", $date->getTimestamp());
    $formatted_time_scnpart = strftime("%H:%M", $date_scn->getTimestamp());

    $evenname  = $event->title;
    $bad_words = array('Example1','Example1','Example2','Example3','Example4','Example5');
    foreach($bad_words as $bad_word){
        if(in_array($eventname, $bad_words)) {
            break;
        } else {
            // This is the modal
            $ray = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
            $cnt = 2;
                echo '<span style="font-weight:400;">'.$cnt++.'. '.'Termin: '.'</span>';
                echo '<span>'.$formatted_time.' - '.$formatted_time_scnpart.'</span><br/>';
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see in the first `echo` I already tried to count with a solution from [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-can-you-count-in-a-foreach-loop-in-PHP) but because I am already inside a foreach, this won't work and would break the other code. (or at least I don't know how)

Comment: What are you doing with the second `for`? The `$bad_word` is never used.

Comment: What is your desired output, and what are you getting now?

Comment: `$cnt++` returns the old value and not the incremented one, so if `$cnt = 1` then `$cnt++` will return 1

Comment: @MehdiBounya Yes,I know but it should count up with each loop.

Comment: So then you need to post what exactly you mean by it doesn't work

Comment: @TrippKinetics I am currently getting a `2` as an output, as as has no function. The `$cnt++` needs to count up.

Comment: It's simply because in each iteration you are re-assigning `$cnt` to `2`...

Comment: @MehdiBounya I know, but how can I make it work, I nowhere found a solution for a case like this.

Comment: Just declare your variable before running the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $cnt = 2 before your loop and $cnt++ inside the loop, this way it will count up with the loop starting from 2.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `$cnt` outside `foreach`

like this:

```
$cnt = 2;
foreach($bad_words as $bad_word){
    if(in_array($eventname, $bad_words)) {
        break;
    } else {
        echo '<span style="font-weight:400;">'.$cnt++.'. '.'Termin: '.'</span>';
        echo '<span>'.$formatted_time.' - '.$formatted_time_scnpart.'</span><br/>';
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I would put it just outside the `foreach` it would not work, I needed to put it outside the `for($i=0;$i<7;$i++) { `.